# sed remove lines that starts with a specific pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed command with a regex pattern that works fine with grep. But it's not matching nothing with sed command.

I have a text file and want to delete each line that starts with (wow or waw).

This is the command I'm using But it's not working.

```
sed -i '/^w\(o\|a\)w/d' text.txt
```

I tried using the same pattern with grep and it works fine:

```
grep '^w\(o\|a\)w' text.txt
```

Anything wrong with the regex in the sed command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you can use

```
sed -i '/^w[oa]w/d' file
```

With FreeBSD `sed`, use

```
sed -i '' '/^w[oa]w/d' file
```

Here, `[oa]` is a bracket expression matching either `o` or `a`.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/bP5XIb):

```sh
sed '/^w[oa]w/d' <<< "wow 1
waw 2
wiw 3"
```

Output: `wiw 3`.

Comment: Thanks. that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: The original code should have worked as well, though.  My guess would be that you are on macOS or BSD and need to say `sed -i '' '/^w\(a\|o\)w/d'` (or, of course, more succinctly and idiomatically `sed -i '' '/^w[ao]w/d'`).

Comment: You seem to have dropped a couple of backslashes.